# ActiveForm.js error when using dynamic form

Tags: yii2, yii-widgets

I want use dynamic form widget (Demo 2:file upload)

URL:http://wbraganca.com/yii2extensions/dynamicform-demo2/source-code

Every thing is good but when i prees 'minus' button or 'new' button i recieve this error from ActiveForm.js:

```
TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined
methods.find()
$.fn.yiiActiveForm()
_fixFormValidaton/<()
.each()
jQuery.prototype.each()
_fixFormValidaton()
_addItem()
methods.addItem()
$.fn.yiiDynamicForm()
what is the problem?
```

what's the problem?

my AppAsset :

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
public $basePath = '@webroot';
public $baseUrl = '@web';
public $css = [
    'css/site.css',
    'css/tabs.css',
    'css/tabstyles.css',
];
public $js = [
    'js/cbpFWTabs.js',
    'js/cbpHorizontalMenu.js',
];
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
];
```

}

Comment: have you modified asset bundle ? AppAsset

Comment: I added my AppAsset, i didn't change it.